# Black screen and blinking cursor in left corner after Windows update on Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows-update, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo g570 laptop. After an auto-update got the IRQ less equal message, the computer won't start. It shows a black screen and a blinking cursor in the left corner. The <kbd>F2</kbd> key won't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: What sort of update you went through? Did you update the BIOS?

Make sure you don't have a usb device plugged in or a DVD disc inside your laptop's drive.

Comment: Do you mean Windows Update? Firmware update? BIOS/UEFI update?

Comment: It was a windows update